# How to enable a button in a mouseClicked java

Tags: java, swing, button

I'm new to java and I'm trying to set rdtnAdministrator.setenabled to false when the password wrong, but when i do it it comes op with this, please explain clearly what im doing wrong.

```
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            char[] password = passwordField.getPassword();
            String passString = new String(password);
            if (passString.equalsIgnoreCase("Dave"))
            {
               System.out.println("Correct!");
               int loggedin = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
                int loggedin = 0;
                rdbtnAdministrator.setEnabled(false); // rdbtnAdministrator cannot be resolved
            }



        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(148, 42, 139, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(loginkey);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);


    JRadioButton rdbtnAdministrator = new JRadioButton("Administrator");
    rdbtnAdministrator.setEnabled(false);
    rdbtnAdministrator.setBounds(386, 10, 109, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(rdbtnAdministrator);
```

I know its because its in a mouseClicked but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: "it comes op with this"  I assume "op" = "up", but what do you refer to with "this"?  What is happening?  Is "Wrong!" output?

Comment: Your question is not clear, at least not to me. You've got some code that appears to be part of a MouseListener, but I don't see anywhere where you add a MouseListener to anything. And perhaps you really should be coding for an ActionListener and not a MouseListener if it's supposed to be activated by a JButton.

Comment: I've also deleted your [tag:javascript] tag since your question has *nothing* to do with JavaScript. You do understand the difference between Java and JavaScript is immense, right? It's like the difference between ham and hamburger.

Comment: rdbtnAdministrator cannot be resolved, I am unsure how to enable the button because of this.Basically, if in the passwordfield the word Dave is typed, the radio box becomes "enabled"

Comment: I have phrased this question badly, ad upon reading it am ashamed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdbtnAdministrator` must be defined accessible within the context of the event handler. You haven't pasted enough code but I assume this is an anonymous class.

The easiest fix would be to define `rdbtnAdministrator` as `final` and do so above the definition of the event handler. Alternatively you can define `rdbtnAdministrator` as an instance member; that is a class level variable instead of a local variable.

Please take the time to learn about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be declaring `rdbtnAdministrator` within a local context, which means that the `MouseListener` has not idea what the variable means...it's out of scope.

Best solution is to make a `rdbtnAdministrator` a class instance variable, then it will become available to the class instance.